# homepage.php Hack Doesn't Work on Media Temple (DV) Server

Tags: php, media-temple

I'm using the [Publish Prefixes](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/publish-prefixes) extension, and I ran into [this problem](https://github.com/elliotlewis/publish_prefixes/commit/89f12bc0efc20a661ccc09b2faad74c668d128f0).

I applied the fix given in the issue tracker, and it works on my local WAMP server and Rackspace Cloud hosting. But it *doesn't* work on Media Temple (DV) servers - the PHP errors remain.

Is there some special PHP setting I need to have in place for this fix to work?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this change shouldn't fail on a different host, but check the obvious, first:

- double-check that you've uploaded the homepage.php file to MT
- does the homepage.php file have the correct permissions on MT
- are your EE versions the same in each case
- are the hosts PHP versions the same in each case

If it isn't something obvious, can you update your post with more info on what the problem is: what looks broken? what error messages are you seeing? what else seems wrong?